# How do I stop Windows Media Player 12 auto playing CD's?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, autoplay

I've set autoplay to "Take no action" on all devices and file types in Windows 7, but Windows Media Player 12 seems to completely ignore this. I can't find a setting in any of the media player options either.

How do I prevent Windows Media Player 12 autoplaying CD's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what i found when i googled for this problem, hope this works for you though this registry edit is meant for Windows Media Player 10:

> I checked my other machine and found
> the same behavior described above when
> previously it did not autoplay a CD
> when Media Player 10 was open. So I
> poked around the registry and found
> that the CDAutoPlay key was set to 1
> on both machines under
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences].
> I changed CDAutoPlay to 0 and things
> are as they were before. Hope this
> helps others users having the same
> issue.

*[Link to the original post](http://forums.techguy.org/multimedia/543466-solved-how-disable-autoplay-windows.html)*

In case you have to add it, `CDAutoPlay` is a DWORD 32-bit value.

Comment: That does indeed still work in WM12. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So I poked around the registry and found that the CDAutoPlay key was set to 1 on both machines under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences].

On my machine that key was not present, but adding it manually worked. WMP now doesn't start to play the CDs I insert.
Annoying feature - kept interrupting what I was already playing.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem partially.

Make the following additions in the registry and the playback is not "unrecoverable"

1. Open Regedit
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences
3. Create a DWORD with name "MediaFolderDetectionDepth" and set its value to "0"
4. Create a DWORD with name "NonMediaCountToAbortMediaFolderDetection" and set its value to "0"

Now, I put in a DVD with some media files,  and mp3 playback does not stop. (previously this was stopping the playback)

In case of inserting a DVD, then I had to stop the playback and press "Play Previous List" in the "Now Playing Window"

Restart is not required. (I see that WMP12 is reading the key atleast one time when the drive is inserted). May be my answer is incomplete. If so, someone please help me (I will also work on this)

I hope this was useful to some level.